# "Handling signal: ttou" message while running DAG in airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, gunicorn

I have created sample DAG, where I had DAG config as below.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',         
    'depends_on_past': False, 
    'start_date': one_min_ago,
    'email': ['admin@airflow.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True, 
    'email_on_retry': True, 
    'retries': 5, 
    'retry_delay': timedelta(hours=30))
```

With this when I run airflow webserver I'm getting below message.

```
/home/af_user/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: 
ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use 
flask_cache instead.
 .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
[2017-12-18 12:41:27,967] [17328] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the 
DagBag from /home/af_user/airflow/dags
[2017-12-18 12:41:28 +0000] [16648] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
[2017-12-18 12:41:57 +0000] [16655] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 16655)
```

And also DAG will be there in running state only.

Let me know if any once came across this issue and fixed it already.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Those messages are expected. The `ttou` (and `ttin`) signals are used to refresh gunicorn workers of the webserver so that it picks up DAG changes. You can modify or disable this behavior with the `worker_refresh_interval` and `worker_refresh_batch_size` [airflow config](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg) values.

Comment: I have some doubts about: "... gunicorn workers of the webserver so that it picks up DAG changes". If you set the worker_refresh_batch_size to 0 in order to disable the refreshing, changes in your DAGs (add or modifications) are still processed.

Comment: [the default value for worker_refresh_interval is 30s](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#worker-refresh-interval) is it required that often? this seems to be causing fairly high cpu usage

Answer (score 1):

I don't really want to change `worker_refresh_interval` or `worker_refresh_batch_size` without a good reason. An alternative is to set an environment variable:

```
GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--log-level WARNING"
```

If setting this in a `docker-compose.yml` file, the following is tested with apache-airflow==1.10.6 with gunicorn==19.9.0:

```
environment:
    - 'GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS=--log-level WARNING'
```

If setting this in a `Dockerfile`, the following is tested with apache-airflow==1.10.6 with gunicorn==19.9.0:

```
ENV GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS --log-level WARNING
```

---

Credit: [answer by amoskaliov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55809197/)